# Having trouble using external JPanel with JTabbed pane

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm learning to create a GUI in school.  I have made these 2 separate JPanels.  Im trying to create a tabbed pane that adds includes each of these in seeparate tabs.  When I open run the code I get three separate windows.  One is a window with 2 blank tabs.  The other 2 windows are the panels that I want to be inside each tab.  Could someone please help me.

```
    package Week4;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabP2 {

    private JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame("Week 4");
    private JTabbedPane ourTabbedPane;
    private JPanel masterContainer, tab1, tab2;

    TabP2(){

        masterContainer = (JPanel) ourFrame.getContentPane();

        masterContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ourTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        tab1 = new OfficeAreaCalculator();

        tab2 = new DayGUI();

        ourTabbedPane.addTab("Office Area Calculator", tab1);
        ourTabbedPane.addTab("DayGUI", tab2);

        masterContainer.add(ourTabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ourFrame.pack();
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run() {
    new TabP2();
}
});
    }
}
```

and

```
package Week4;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.*;


public class DayGUI2 extends JPanel{

    private JButton cmdGood;
    private JButton cmdBad;

    public DayGUI2(){       

        cmdGood = new JButton("Good");
        cmdBad = new JButton("Bad");        

        setBackground(Color.white);

        add(cmdGood);
        cmdGood.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(cmdBad);
        cmdBad.setBackground(Color.red);

        cmdGood.setMnemonic('G');
        cmdBad.setMnemonic('B');

        ButtonsHandler bhandler = new ButtonsHandler();
        cmdGood.addActionListener(bhandler);
        cmdBad.addActionListener(bhandler);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonsHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if (e.getSource() == cmdGood)               
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a good day!",
                        "Event Handler Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            if (e.getSource() == cmdBad)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a bad day!",
                        "Event Handler Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

I would add the other one but I don't see the need.  Its setup is almost identical.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You got like 3 WINDOWS? With Minimalize, Maximalize and Close buttons ???????

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post screenshot

Comment: I get one window which has two tabs.  I get another window that has DayGUI working in it and another window the the OfficeAreaCalculator in it.

Comment: Which IDE are you programming this in?

Comment: eclipse.  Its what we have to use for class.  We can't use something  like netbeans

Comment: Try removing the main methods from your JPanel classes. You only need a single entry point for your program, so a single main method in `TabP2` should be enough. I doubt you'd be able to run all of those at once (you say you get frames), but you can make sure they can't be ran that way.

Comment: I deleted the main method in the classes.  And I can now assume that the problem is due to the code in the external classes DayGUI2.java and OfficaAreaCalculator2.java.  It seems like whenever they are initialized it creates a new window for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to removing unnecessary main methods, so you have only one, here are some pointers for you.

You don't need to instantiate new panels to put your panels into in order to have them as tabs.

```java
tab1 = new JPanel();
OfficeAreaCalculator OAC = new OfficeAreaCalculator();
tab1.add(OAC);

tab2 = new JPanel();
DayGUI Day = new DayGUI();
tab1.add(Day);

ourTabbedPane.addTab("Office Area Calculator", tab1);
ourTabbedPane.addTab("DayGUI", tab2);
```

As you indicate in the question, these classes already extend `JPanel`, so simply instantiate them and add them as tabs.

```java
tab1 = new OfficeAreaCalculator();

tab2 = new DayGUI();

ourTabbedPane.addTab("Office Area Calculator", tab1);
ourTabbedPane.addTab("DayGUI", tab2);
```

Before calling `setVisible(true)`, you might want to call `pack()`, so your frame is sized correctly upon being shown.

```java
ourFrame.pack();
ourFrame.setVisible(true);
ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Also, when constructing GUI with Swing in java, always delegate your GUI code to Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) in order to avoid threading problems. Swing runs in it's own thread - the EDT - which is different from your main thread. You are currently invoking Swing code from your main thread, which is a bad idea, so do this instead:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        new TabP2();
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand everything you said except for the threading part.  I looked it up on google and it's still a little confusing.  The content is still opening in separate windows.  Thanks for your help on this so far.

Comment: Nevermind, it works.  I just spent an hour realizing that I was making a mistake.  I named all the classes with a 2 because I didn't want to mess up my original work.  But then after editing over and over I was calling the original class which was wrong.  You're the best.  Thanks!

Comment: You can read more about Swing threading in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all add your panels to `JTabbedPane` as tabs via `addTab` method not with `add` method.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) link and [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) tutorial

```
    ourTabbedPane.addTab("Office Area Calculator", tab1);
    ourTabbedPane.addTab("DayGUI", tab2);
```

Comment: the problem I am having is to get the information to populate in the tab.  I tried this and I still cant get it to work

  ourTabbedPane.addTab(null, tab1);
  ourTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("Office Area Calculator"));

Comment: How about screenshot?